# JavaFx JFoenix Java9

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix, javafx-9

so I updated my Java from 8 to 9, and I do realize that Jfoenix has separate Jar file for Java 9.
However after download the Jar file then trying to import to Scene builder like I did before, nothing shows up, None of the custom controller shows up when I trying to import.[image: scene builder 2.0 import new Jar file]
Can anyone tell me what is going on ?

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you are using Gluon Scene Builder 9.0.1, that can be downloaded from [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download).

Once installed, go to the Jar/FXML Manager option:

[image]

Select `Search repositories`:

[image]

Type `JFoenix`. Select the first option:

[image]

Click `Add Jar`. The latest dependency will be used. In this case, `com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.1`.

You will find all the controls from the library:

[image]

Finally click `Import Components`. You can start using them by dragging the controls from the Custom pane.

Note that you can also select manually other dependency versions, clicking the `Manually add Library from repository` option from the Library Manager, and selecting the desired version based on the group and artifact.

[image]