# Importing a JAR into SceneBuilder not working

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am using SceneBuilder-9.0.1 and trying to use JFoenix. While trying to import the jfoenix-9.0.1.jar with the JAR/FXML Manager (Library Managger), the following error appears:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

I have no problems with importing FXML files though. The same error occurs if I try to import other JARs, e.g. controlsfx.

I think it's strange that the Scene Builder wants to copy the file into \Roaming\Scene Builder/Library because that's no valid file path, isn't it? Is there any way of coyping the file manually without using the Library Manager? And if yes, where do I need to copy the JAR file to? And is this a problem of SceneBuilder or of my PC?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180260/javafx-jfoenix-java9). It should install the jar in your local maven repository.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. But i do see the Import Dialog and can select the components. The error occurs after hitting "Import Components". I tried to search for "com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.1" in the repositories but it tells me that there are no items available. I suspect that's because i have to use a proxy.

Comment: But you can install ControlsFX or other jars, using `Search Repositories`?

Comment: No, i don't find any jars using Search Repositories (because i use a proxy). If i try to import controlsfx from the file system, it gives me the same error.

Comment: Have you defined a `settings.xml` file with your proxy settings? See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251216/3956070) for instance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! The tech support team of my company has answered my mail now and it seems like a company guideline problem. So no JARs for me :(